# Unity URP Texture isn't showing up right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, urp

[image: The Texture]

[image: The Result]

[image: Result Zoomed In]

Hello, does anyone know why my texture isn't showing up right?
It is my first time using Unity URP and I tried to add a texture to my plane.
That worked but the result is confusing..

```
textureRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
```

I added the texture to the material and it seems right in the inspector.

Another point is that I only see the result when I zoom in a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uncheck the fog via Window->Rendering->Lighting->Enviroment->Fog